# JAX RS and application/x-www-form-urlencoded with Multiple Parameters

Tags: curl, postman, jax-rs, x-www-form-urlencoded

I´m trying to get the values from my x-www-form-urlencoded, but MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams the doesn´t include any value:

```
@POST
    @Path("/submitForm")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public Response getFormDataUsingMultivaluedMap(@Context HttpServletRequest request,
            @HeaderParam(ConstantsWebservice.X_API_KEY) String formKey,
            MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
        
    for (String key : formParams.keySet()) {
```

Here my CURL:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/service/formintegration/submitForm' \
--header 'X-API-KEY: 123456789' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'test=test'
```

I have currently no idea why the list doesn´t include the "test".

I´ve tried also with Postman:
[image]

Any idea what´s wrong?

Comment: You might have to use `@FormParam`. In some cases, the parameters will be read from the HttpServletRequest, leaving it empty. I think it has to do with some servlet filter reading them. If you have some third-party filter running, this might happen.

Comment: @PaulSamsotha But than I have to define for 10 Parameters 10 times @FormParam? I need this Dynamic.

Comment: Do you see a warning in the logs that say _"... the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter"_ ?

Comment: Unfortunately not.... I have tried also with Form form in the function parameter list. Also not working

Comment: I know a way, but it doesn't look that great. What Jersey does it put the form into a property. You can retrieve that property through an injected ContainerRequest. See [this](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/7b6d2f84391f24310baae7d8e55e644703642826/containers/jersey-servlet-core/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/servlet/WebComponent.java#L610)

Comment: Also a @BeanParam is another option.

Comment: Thanks..... but with @BeanParam I need a Entity, right? ContainerRequest is not working for me, seems like it´s not in the JAX RS Wildfly included?

Comment: Yea, it's a Jersey thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232432/discussion-between-vished2000-and-paul-samsotha).

Comment: This seems it´s working:  Map<String, String[]> test = request.getParameterMap();
   Map<String, String> pluginParameterMap = new HashMap<>();

   for (String parameterName : test.keySet()) {
    String[] values = test.get(parameterName);
    if (values != null && values.length > 0) {
     pluginParameterMap.put(parameterName, values[0]);
    } else {
     pluginParameterMap.put(parameterName, null);
    }
   } but I´m noit sure if this is the right way